# Rendering results of filter with react native

Tags: react-native

I've this....

```
renderSearchResults() {
    if (!this.props.events.successfully) {
        return
    }
    //This don't work
    /*
 return (
     <View>
         {
             this.props.events.data.data.filter(flt =>
                 flt.location.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchText.toLowerCase()))
                 .map(item => {
                     alert(item)
                     return (<View style={style.searchResultsWrapper} key={'ev' + item.id}>
                         <EventItem data={item}></EventItem>
                     </View>)
                 })
         }
     </View>
 )
 */
    //This Works
    return (
        <View>
            {
                this.props.events.data.data.map(item => {
                    return (
                        <View style={style.searchResultsWrapper} key={'ev' + item.id}>
                        <EventItem data={item}></EventItem>
                        </View>
                    )
                })
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```

I need to make the non-working code to work. Actually the alert line executes fine, so it means that's iterating fine. However this can't render results. Any clue ?

I just put the working code to demonstrante that this works ok without the filter. Is there something that I did't get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code run properly with some change like in the below in my demo code. Maybe you look your all component and try with a  component like in the below.

```
 <View>
     {
        this.props.events.data.data.filter(flt =>
             flt.location.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchText.toLowerCase()))
             .map(item => {
                 alert(item)
                 return (<View key={'ev' + item.id}>
                     <Text>{item.location}</Text>
                 </View>)
             })
     }
 </View>
```

Comment: Not working..I've placed : return(
            <View>
                {
                    return this.props.events.data.data.filter(flt =>
                    flt.location.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchText.toLowerCase()))
                    .map(item => {
                    alert(item)
                    return (<View style={style.searchResultsWrapper} key={'ev' + item.id}>
                    <EventItem data={item}></EventItem>
                    </View>)
                })
                }
            </View>
        )

Comment: Syntax Error. After the 1st bracket, my editor complains "}" expected

Comment: Firstly i misunderstood your code actually right and must work. I edited my post. Maybe you can try Text instead of EventItem too.